# How to factorise following equation?

Tags: factoring

Given,

$$\frac{2xz-1}{z} + \frac{2xy-1}{x} + \frac{2yz-1}{y} = 3$$

I have tried this in so many ways but unable to factorise.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by “factorize” the equation?

Comment: @Michael Hope like getting (x-2z)(y-z)=0 something like that.

Comment: The nicest form I was able to get it into, by multiplying across by $xyz$ and then collecting like terms, is: $$2xyz(x+y+z)-(xy+yz+xz)=3xyz$$